# Row Chart grouping on two text dimensions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Using this fake dataset:

[image: Data]

I want to make a row chart that has two rows, one for the `savings_1` total and one for `savings_2` total.

Something like:

```
savings_1 [            1970            ]
savings_2 [   258   ]
```

I am pretty new to dc.js and d3.js so I am not sure how to structure the group/dimension to make this possible.

```
var savingsDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return 'Savings 1'
}), savingsDimensionGroup = noDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.savings_1
});
```

Using that dimension and group, it gives me the total for just one of the savings. I feel like there is a way to get both groupings with the same group/dimension.

Comment: See also this follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34299017/676195

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for linking those questions. The first one was definitely what I was looking for and it worked perfectly.