# dc.js pie-chart combine 2 columns

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a table.

```
year,continent,state,export_value,import_value,all
2013,Африка,Angola,94061754,220518.54,94282272.54
2013,Африка,Burundi,4136818,1239175.91,5375993.91
2013,Африка,Benin,3251643.49,65421.6,3317065.09
```

I need to make a pie chart using dc.js:

[image: import/export pie chart]

Here is what I tried:

```
    impexDim            = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return ((d.export_value > 0 ? 'Export' : 'Import') 
                                        && (d.import_value > 0 ? 'Import' : 'Export')) ;}),

    groupeimpexDim      = impexDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.all}),
```

How do I display the columns `export_value` and `import_value` as slices of the pie chart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js - how to create a row chart from multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737277/dc-js-how-to-create-a-row-chart-from-multiple-columns)

Comment: Hello! I believe this is a duplicate of the above linked question, but if you can't figure it out or it doesn't work, please comment and I'll help. As in that question, I don't think you can use this chart to filter others: since every row contributes to both pie slices, there is no way to select rows based on these categories.

Comment: Sorry for my English.
Thanks for help.
But this example doesn't work, when you press the row-chart, pie-chart don't modify.

Comment: Yeah, as I explained above, filtering using this kind of dimension/group doesn't make any sense at all. Crossfilter needs the rows mapped to some keys - so this mapping puts the rows into disjoint sets. Then it filters on the rows. What would you expect filtering on Exports to do? All countries have exports.

Comment: Russia's trade with countries of the world, filters across countries and continents

Comment: Sure, it makes sense to filter on country or continent. But how would you filter on Exports?

Comment: Exports and imports are filtered by types product, goods and services.

Comment: That's not in this data. Do you mean to filter some other data?

Comment: Yes. I now have such dashboards.[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhh0n8mqopx2gqj/dash.png?dl=0)

I need show in pie-chart exports and imports balance of trade.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This code in the linked question will let you display imports and exports in the pie chart based on the selected countries and continents in other charts. It won't let you click on exports and imports because there is no way to filter by imports and exports using this data.

Comment: Note that in the other example it's the row chart using column-based groups, that's why clicking the row chart does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for help, I understand you, we will find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I guess it could trigger a filter on something else (another crossfilter instance, for example) - it's just that there's nothing in_this_ data to filter via imports/exports.