# Show multiple values total count in ring graph dc js with crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have one json example below:

```
{"Year":2018,"Month":1,"ApplicationName":"application1","ASI":12.0,"AEI":11.0},
{"Year":2018,"Month":2,"ApplicationName":"application2","ASI":24.0,"AEI":12.0}
```

I want to show a ring chart with two slices:

1. total of ASI
2. total of AEI

How can I get crossfilter to produce the two bins for the two columns?

Comment: By ring graph, do you mean a pie chart with a hole in the center like the [Quarters chart on the main page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)? That's done by setting [innerRadius](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.pieChart.html#innerRadius__anchor). As for showing the total, you can just use [group.reduceSum()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduceSum) with an accessor that adds the fields you care about.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for reply. Will reduceSum() return total of each value ?? let say "ASI" total count and "AEI" total count. I think  reduceSum() can return either "AEI" total count or "ASI" total count. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js - how to create a row chart from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737277/dc-js-how-to-create-a-row-chart-from-multiple-columns)

Comment: Hi, I came to know what I am trying to do is not possible in cross filter. My code will only create the pie chart of "ASI" and  "AEI" but not filter other graphs on clicking them as the filter I am trying to apply in other graph is not valid. Some one asked to do the same as I am trying but you cleared that is not possible because I am trying to filter "ASI" and "AEI" which is not possible for other graphs to filter and it is meaning less filtering. Sharing  link where i got cleared about my problem. Thanks Gordan. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135743/dc-js-pie-chart-combine-2-columns

Comment: Thanks for following up. Yes, since each row contributes to both ASI and AEI, there is no way to choose rows to filter based on these values. I don't know what your data represents, but maybe it could be put in a format which could work, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

The accessor used by `reduceSum` is a general function; you can put anything you want in there.

Thus,

```
group.reduceSum(function(d) { return d.ASI + d.AEI; });
```

will instruct the group to sum up all the ASIs and all the AEIs from the rows which fall into each bin.

Comment: This will sum all d.ASI + all d.AEI right? I want each individual sum and show in pie.Modified my json ,code is below tell I am correct or not?
 var ASI = 0;AEI = 0;arr = [];
 for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
 if(data[i].ASI){ASI += json[i].ASI;}
 if(data[i].AEI){AEI += json[i].AEI;}
 arr.push({"type":"ASI","count":ASI});arr.push({"type":"AEI","count":AEI});
    var typedimen = cf.dimension(function(d){return d.type});
 var typegroup = typedimen.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.count; });

Comment: Yes it will sum all ASI and all AEI. But I'm not sure what you are trying to do with all that code. Crossfilter already does all the aggregation. If you sum everything before hand then it won't be able to filter. Please look at some crossfilter examples - there are lots out there.

Comment: I have created js fiddle now. What I am trying to do is in my js fiddle first graph which is grouped by "ApplicationName" and reducesum by "chats" but in the second graph i have mutiple values like "ASI" and "AEI" i am unable to reducesum multiple values for that reason i have written my own function. Please check whether my code is fine or not as you are saying i would not be able to filter. Please check and correct my code there. Below 
 is the url                                                                   
http://jsfiddle.net/25xtp/24/

Comment: Okay, I've edited your question for clarity, and suggested a duplicate. Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for.