# Creating multiple column dimension from csv

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to make a pie chart using multiple columns from a csv file, I can produce a pie chart but it only use the last value d.gre. What am I doing wrong?

Code is below

```
d3.csv("elecVotes.csv", function (data) {

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var partysDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d.rep, +d.dem, +d.lib, +d.ind, +d.gre;})
var partys = partysDim.group();

var pie = dc.pieChart('#chart-pie');

pie
    .width(180)
    .height(180)
    .radius(80)
    .dimension(partysDim)
    .group(partys)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .innerRadius(10)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .colorAccessor(function (d, i) { return d.value; });

    dc.renderAll();
});
```

electVotes.csv

`state, rep,dem,lib,ind,gre 
Alabama,1314431,725704,44211,20276,9341
New York,5655,54444,65666,2355,12225
Texas,4355,543234,12321,12331,45644`

Comment: You probably need to transform your data to be better structured for Crossfilter. Can you share some sample data please? I'll be able to suggest a transformation that should work for you. A working example would be especially helpful, but not completely necessary here.

Comment: `state, rep,dem,lib,ind,gre                                                                        
Alabama,725704,44211,20276,9341` This is my current data I'm using, I would like to implement this so that when I click on states on a geographic map that it updates based on which state is clicked

Comment: @EthanJewett i've updated this with some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's suggestion should work, but I would also urge you to consider getting the data into a more appropriate format up front. It will make your life easier in a lot of ways and when using a lot of different tools. Specifically, you would need to transform your file to having only three columns: State, Party, and Votes. If you are maintaining this data in Excel, do it there. Or you can run this on the file you load:

```
var newData = []
data.forEach(function(d) {
  newData.push({state: d.state, party: 'rep', votes: d.rep})
  newData.push({state: d.state, party: 'dem', votes: d.dem})
  newData.push({state: d.state, party: 'lib', votes: d.lib})
  newData.push({state: d.state, party: 'ind', votes: d.ind})
  newData.push({state: d.state, party: 'gre', votes: d.gre})
})
data = newData
```

Then your Crossfilter dimension and group creation will look like this:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var partysDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.party;})
var partys = partysDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.votes;});
```

Again, this is another way of handling the same problem. I think there are big payoffs from organizing your data the right way up front so I usually recommend doing that work and then keeping the Crossfilter/dc.js code nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't sure how to properly organise my data and this makes so much more sense now. I was working on what I had learnt from database and not wanting to have redundant data. Cheers.

Comment: Cool - and yeah, heavy normalization is not good for analytics. A lot of teaching tells that more normalization is always better and you want at least 3rd normal form, but that's a view that is heavily focused on transactional workloads on traditional row-oriented RDBMS systems. It doesn't hold up on different types of database systems (Crossfilter is kind of like a columnar engine) and workloads. For analytics you often want to prioritize tall tables with as few measure columns as possible.

Comment: Just out of interest if I wanted to add another column of data say ElecVotes for each state should I just add another column and only input one data entry for it? or one for each albama entity.

Comment: Is this `elecVotes = rep + dev + lib + ind + gre` or something entirely different?

Comment: It would be a completely new column called elec votes which would have the ammount of electoral votes for each state

Comment: Oh, got it. Yes, you can do this and want to put it in each row, but the obvious wrinkle is that you want to only count it once. 2 options: 1) Keep the electoral vote counts off to the side and look them up in the dc.js chart accessors based on the group keys (states) or 2) Put them on every row of the data and use a custom group to only count them once per state (Reductio exception aggregation can do this: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#exception-aggregation). For this use-case, I'd recommend #1

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here. On the JavaScript level, the comma "operator" just evaluates both sides of the comma and returns the second. So the value of

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

is just `5`. So that explains the result you're currently getting.

The other problem is more conceptual. Crossfilter is not designed to display each column in a group. I think the main reason is that there would be no way to filter by political party, since each region or state has values for every party. You would need data at the voter level to filter by party.

Given that restriction, you definitely won't be able to filter by clicking on the pie chart. However, with a little work, you can have the pie chart display the column sums as bins of a group.

As Ethan says, maybe it's better to transform your data, but [this answer shows how to produce a group which rotates the data on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747518/676195).