# Multidimension Bubble Chart using DC.js

Tags: multidimensional-array, dc.js, crossfilter, bubble-chart

I am trying to create a bubble chart using DC.js

> The sample data I have is:

```
State_Name  Area    Cities    Villages   Population
A           200      60          1050      10000
B           300      80          1100      15678
C           500      20          2220      97767
D           600      90          3400      50000
```

So, I want to show total three Bubbles on a `bubbleChart`. The first bubble should represent **total Area** and rest two should represent **total Cities** and **total Villages** respectively. I have made a `barChart` for `States_Names` vs `Population` where `xAxis` represent `States_name` and `yAxis` represent `Population`. Now I want whenever I click on one or more bars or you can say `States_name` I should get the sum of Area, Cities and Villages for all those selected `States_name`. These sum values for `Area`, `Cities` and `Villages` will represent three bubbles on `bubbleChart` respectively.

> For example: if I click on two bars from `barChart` which represent `State_Name` = `A` and `B` respectively, I
>   should get three bubbles on `bubbleChart`. On hovering these three
>   bubbles I should get values total `Area` = 200+300= 500,  Total
>   `Cities` = 60+80 = 140, total `Villages` = 1050+1100 = 2150 respectively.
>
> **For Positioning of bubbles:**
>   I can fix their `yAxis` position. And, their `xAxis` position and `radius` should depend on the value that bubble has. For above example radius of bubble representing total `Villages` should be larger than the radius of other two bubbles. Similarly, for `xAxis` position bubble representing total `Cities` will be on left side of other two bubbles.
>
> I tried code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/37uET/6/
>   but getting the error: **"group.top is not a function"**. It seems
>   that code works only for rowChart.

```
var data = [
        {type: 'foo', a: 10, b: 9, c: 11, d: 2},
        {type: 'bar', a: 1, b: 4, c: 2, d: 3},
        {type: 'foo', a: 0, b: 2, c: 1, d: 22},
        {type: 'bar', a: 11, b: 5, c: 6, d: 5}];
    var ndx1 = crossfilter(data);

    function regroup(dim, cols) {
        var _groupAll = dim.groupAll().reduce(
            function(p, v) { // add
                cols.forEach(function(c) {
                    p[c] += v[c];
                });
                return p;
            },
            function(p, v) { // remove
                cols.forEach(function(c) {
                    p[c] -= v[c];
                });
                return p;
            },
            function() { // init
                var p = {};
                cols.forEach(function(c) {
                    p[c] = 0;
                });
                return p;
            });
        return {
            all: function() {
                // or _.pairs, anything to turn the object into an array
                return d3.map(_groupAll.value()).entries();
            }
        };
    }

    var dim = ndx1.dimension(function(r) { return r.a; });
    var sidewaysGroup = regroup(dim, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

    var typeDim = ndx.dimension(function(r) { return r.type; });

    var sidewaysRow = dc.bubbleChart('#state-donations')
            .width(350).height(300)
            .dimension(dim)
            .group(sidewaysGroup)
            .elasticX(true)
            .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.3)
                        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
                        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
                        .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 400]))
                        .elasticY(true)
                        .yAxisPadding(100)
                        .elasticX(true)
                        .xAxisPadding(500);
```

please help!

Comment: You should add more detail and maybe a picture of what you're trying to do, and some code you tried. It doesn't sound like the same kind of bubble chart that dc.js offers - I don't see X and Y coordinates here, maybe you are looking for a [bubble cloud](http://intellipharm.github.io/dc-addons/#bubble-cloud)?

Comment: @Gordon I have attached the code I had tried.

Comment: You still need to spell out your question better - now I understand that you want to display a bubble for each column (which requires rotating the data), but most people couldn't guess that. Also I still don't understand how you plan to apply this to a bubble chart, which normally has X and Y coordinates for each bubble. Asking good questions is hard!

Comment: Hi @Gordon , I have edited my question for better understanding. I hope now it is clear to you.

Comment: Okay, how are the bubbles arranged in the chart, what are their positions? I still think you may be thinking about a bubble cloud rather than a bubble chart.

Comment: @Gordon well, I can fix their `yAxis` position. And, their `xAxis` position and `radius` should depend on the value that bubble has. **For above example radius of bubble representing total `Villages` should be larger than the radius of other two bubbles. Similarly, for `xAxis` position bubble representing total `Cities` will be on left side of other two bubbles.**

Comment: Okay, include this in the question and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @gordan I have included that in the question as you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, I've voted to reopen, let's see if others follow. What if two columns have the same value, e.g. what if total cities ends up the same as total area? Then the bubbles will be on top of each other.

Comment: Well, this question is still on hold, but I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737277/dc-js-how-to-create-a-row-chart-from-multiple-columns#24747518) covers most of what you're looking for. Note that clicking on the bubbles won't filter anything, because the rows of your data contribute to all bubbles.