# chart using multiple data from a single row

Tags: dc.js

In my data I have multiple columns containing sensor data, eg:
time,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,etc.

I would like to create a row/bar/pie chart with the count/avg/etc. where every row, bar or pie segment is a different sensor. Until now I haven't figured out, how to achieve this, because in the examples the dimension always selects one value.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You won't be able to filter very well using column-based items, or the semantics will be confusing, because crossfilter can only filter by row. But here is I think the canonical duplicate question, which contains pointers to further embellishments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js - how to create a row chart from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737277/dc-js-how-to-create-a-row-chart-from-multiple-columns)