# dc.js create pie chart from single row in csv

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, dc.js

I'm trying to create a pie chart using the stat data of pokemon I have in a csv.
For example at id 1, there is Bulbasaur and it's corresponding stats: attack, defense, HP, special attack, special defense and speed.

I want to be able to select a row, and display that stat data in a pie chart.

I've already got each stat as a crossfilter dimension, but I'm lost on selecting the row and generating the chart from that.

Comment: Note that you will not be able to click on the pie slices, because crossfilter only filters on rows, not on columns. I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate, but speak up if it doesn't match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js - how to create a row chart from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737277/dc-js-how-to-create-a-row-chart-from-multiple-columns)