# dc.js Box Plot - TypeError: data.map(...).sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to make a Box Plot with 4 boxes from a single crossfilter dimension of objects that have 16 values, not all of which are numbers.  I want the values to come from A, C, C2 and G.  For some reason, I am getting an error saying data.map.sort is not a function:

[image]

Example object:

```
A: 6.666666666666665
AN: 18
C: 9.999999999999998
CN: 28
C2: 10
C2N: 21
G: 2.0000000000000013
GN: 19
N/A: NaN
analyze_url: "some string"
collection_mode: "default"
collector_id: "some irrelevant number"
custom_value: ""
custom_variables: {}
date_created: "2019-09-15T12:06:47+00:00"
date_modified: "2019-09-15T12:16:50+00:00"
```

Creating Box Plot:

```
dimension = createDimension(ndx);
    let columns = ['G', 'C', 'C2', 'A']

    function createBoxPlot() {
        const boxPlot = new dc.BoxPlot(divRef);
        let group = dimension.group().reduce(
            function reduceAdd(p, v) {
                columns.forEach(function(c) {
                    // keep array sorted for efficiency
                    p[c].splice(d3.bisectLeft(p[c], v[c]), 0, v[c] || 0);
                });
                return p || 0;
            },
            function reduceRemove(p, v) {
                columns.forEach(function(c) {
                    p[c].splice(d3.bisectLeft(p[c], v[c]), 1);
                });
                return p || 0;
            },
            function reduceInitial() {
                let p = {};
                columns.forEach(function(c) {
                    p[c] = [];
                });
                return p || 0;
            });
        boxPlot
            .dimension(dimension)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
            .group(group)
            .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                console.log(p);
                return p || 0;
            })
            // .elasticY(true)
            // .elasticX(true)
            .width(700)
            .height(500);
        return boxPlot;
    }

    return createBoxPlot();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: data.map(...).sort is not a function
SVGGElement.<anonymous>
node_modules/dc/dist/dc.js:4674
  4671 | // For each small multiple…
  4672 | function box (g) {
  4673 |     g.each(function (data, index) {
> 4674 |         data = data.map(value).sort(d3Array.ascending);
  4675 |         const _g = d3Selection.select(this);
  4676 |         const n = data.length;
  4677 |         let min;
```

Comment: By default, the box plot expects the values in the group's key/value pairs to be arrays of values. But your reducer is creating an object, indexed by column name, of arrays of values. Do you mean to select a particular column in your `valueAccessor`?

Comment: I do, however, replacing `return p || 0` with `return p.G || 0` produces the same error.  Ideally I want to return all 4 columns.

Comment: `|| 0` is not helping you because the box plot wants an array. It would be `|| []` to avoid errors. What format does your log tell you the data is in? What do you want to do with the four columns, simply aggregate them? The box plot doesn’t have another dimension available.

Comment: Replacing 0 with [] fixes the error, however no boxes still.  The log tells me the data has keys that match what I have in the example object in my question above, however every other log has null keys. The values are always arrays of values, i.e A:[4.888888888888889, 6.000000000000001].  I was hoping to have 4 boxes, each corresponding to one of the 4 columns of the dimension, I'm not sure if that was what you meant by aggregate them.

Comment: I got it to work for one column, by having a try/catch statement in the `valueAccessor`.  I think this works because some entries have missing values or NaN.  However how can I have all 4 columns have a box on the plot?  The valueAccessor only seems to be able to handle one column.

Comment: Crossfilter is row oriented: it wants to throw rows into bins and filter by rows. You can fake it out to create bins which are columns, but it takes a little work. It usually involves groupAll, not group. Here is a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24737277 . Note that filtering may have unexpected behavior.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! For reference, I had employed the technique from [stackoverflow.com/q/24737277](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24737277)