# Column averages not calculating correctly from Python Panda to crossfilter

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, dc.js, crossfilter

I hope you can forgive me... I might have been a litttlle misleading with my title. The columns are calculating correctly... but not the way I would like them to.

What I have is the hourly weather measurements (temp,precip, etc.) for a city going back 10 years. I then created a dataframe adding the average of each metric as its own column on each respective hour.

This dataset is then fed into dc.js where I aggregate up as needed for different charts.

Everything works great except for [precipitation](http://cl.ly/image/1n461L301y0n) (in inches). It doesn't make sense to simply take the hourly average... I need the sums and then the average... but do i need to handle that condition for each time I roll up? (month, year, etc.)

I'm a little stuck on how to do this. Below is a link to my ipython notebook with my short and commented code. Any help is much appreciated

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Luiz-N/96477b1e327169d010c6

Comment: What do you mean "I need the sums and then the average".   For example, I'm confused what the 2009 yearly average means.  Is it the average rainfall "per day" in 2009?

Comment: Right, thats the problem... (referring to the link with my graphs) I want those to be the average total precip per year, per, month, and per hour respectively. The problem is you can't calculate that with precip levels the way you can with other weather metrics... What I think those charts are currently showing are the average per hour per dimension (year, month, hour).. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, does that make more sense?

Comment: @DJMartin this is my mapReduce average function: (I pass in the dimension and the name of the column I want averaged)


EDIT: (that coffescript did not render well... here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/Luiz-N/b1a00dc612274fc36cad) to the function

Comment: I guess my confusion is how you can have an average yearly precipitation for a single year.  If the total precipitation in 2009 was 20 inches, then the "average yearly precipitation in 2009" would be 20 inches.  It's a "per year" calculation for a single year.

Comment: ah yes, Thank you @DJMartin , that's a good point. So if I wanted to show the actual precip for a year,month, or hour it would just be the reduceSum for that respective dimension. But what I need is to be able to show those numbers next to the average for each respective dimension... (The actual precip levels for June next to the average for June... etc) For my other metrics I was just able to add a column in pands of the hourly average and aggregate up as needed...

Comment: What do you mean by the "actual precip levels for June".  Does that mean the current years June precip compared to the June average over the lifetime of your data?

Comment: @DJMartin you've put me on the right track now... [This](http://cl.ly/image/0l2o2i1n172z) is what i'm trying to create but using precip instead of Temp... I'm thinking I might need to do a special mapreduce for Precip where instead of taking the average I just sum up for each dimension..?

Comment: @DJMartin I just saw your comment, yes that is what i'm trying to do... I realize now that if no time filter is applied the average and actual will be the same on bar charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the latest picture from your comments makes sense now.

[image]
If this chart were standalone (meaning it didn't need to reflect other filters), you could try  preprocessing the monthly averages and then adding that average to your group sum.

```
    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      p.average = monthlyPrecip(v.month);
      p.actual += v.precip;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      p.actual -= v.precip;
      return p;

    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {actual: 0, average: 0};  
    }
```

From there, you could build a composite chart with the two data points.

Does this sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, we're making progress here... I already have a column with the average for each respective hour of the entire dataset of precip... so what i just did was:

`firstChartGroup = monthStamp.group().reduceSum (d) -> d.Precip <br/>
 secondChartGroup = monthStamp.group().reduceSum (d) -> d.Precip_avg`

Where monthstamp is d3.time.month(d.date) calculated at first dataload.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get to finish that last comment... monthstamp is a time dimension created from adding the column d3.time.month(d.date) on first data-load. I then use those two different chartGroups to build the composite chart and get [more reasonable looking numbers....](http://cl.ly/image/263N2y3w3u1m) Will my method not work if the chart is not standalone..?

Comment: Not sure how you got the precip_avg.  It seems that might be a static number (or calculated once at the beginning).  The precip_avg does not seem to be calculated from the crossfilter currently selected rows.  This means that if you applied a filter (perhaps to look at the past 5 years), your precip_avg wouldn't change (compared to the all-time average).

Comment: so each row is one hour of recorded weather data... Before loading the data to crossfilter I calculated the avg for each metric for each respective hour... For example a raw record for Jan 1st 2009 at 2pm has a column for the precip level of that hour and a previp_avg column that is the average precip level for all Jan 1st 2pm precip levels across all years in my dataset... but you're right... If a filter is applied for only the past 5 years then the average calculation for comparison would only be using the past 5 years instead of the whole dataset...

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track.  Creating two groups is a good approach.  Since your precip_avg starts as "the average precip level for all Jan 1st 2pm across all years" this average will not change when you apply other filters.  The average would be the same if you looked at the past 50 years or the past 5 years.  This may be desirable or it may not be.

Comment: But what If I wanted to do something [like this](http://cl.ly/image/1h0G160I173S) except next to each blue bar was a red bar showing the average for that respective year,month,hour (across all time)... that red bar would only be averaging the numbers from within that brush time filter right..? I guess if I got what I wanted the red bars would be static... since those all time averages wold never change... could one chart of a compsoite chart respect a brush filter but the other chart ignore it?

Comment: Here is an answer regarding how to build a composite bar chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961551/multi-series-bar-chart-in-dc-js