# best way to put two time/event-series in one chart

Tags: events, time-series, bar-chart, dc.js

I have a set of data that looks like this

```
event_name, open_date, closed_date
JOBAPPLICATON, 1-jun-2014, 4-jun-2014
JOBAPPLICATON, 3-jun-2014, 4-jun-2014
JOBAPPLICATON, 1-jun-2014, 14-jun-2014
...
```

I would like to plot these in a bar chart with a time scale, in such a way that the open_date is grouped and counted (as a red bar), and the closed_date is grouped and counted (as a blue bar). Ideally, these bars are next-to-each-other.

I achieved some success by combining them in a composedChart as two separate barcharts, but is that the best way? Or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the composed chart in this manner before.

It worked for me because I needed two bars (revenue and cost) for the past year.  It would've been harder if I had a dynamic number of bars or if the time frame would've been variable.

Here is a writeup of that approach: [Multi-series bar chart in DC-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961551/multi-series-bar-chart-in-dc-js/21991057#21991057)

Comment: Yeah, dc.js doesn't really support bar series charts / grouped bar charts yet.  This composite approach is the best I know so far.

Comment: The composed charts have some weird issues with margins though.

Comment: If you can use a fixed time scale (I used one year) and a fixed number of series (I had two) then you should be able to manage the margins.