# dc.js grouped bar chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I need to do this grouped bar chart like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631378/grouped-bar-chart-dc-js) but the .renderType() doesn`t work. Are there any solutions to do a chart like this? Thanks!

Comment: That question [links to a PR](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/984) for doing grouped charts. That version is a bit behind dc.js but the PR links to a branch you can use. If you are using npm/package.json you can specify a github branch instead of a version number. Please try it out!

Comment: And please comment on that PR if you can't get it to work. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you @Gordon

Comment: The problem here is that I'm too beginner to know how to use it. But, I'll 'ask' Google. :D

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I've installed the package and it doesn't work, I get the error that says the '.renderType()' is not a function. I`ve tried on that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's non-trivial to find a branch or fork of dc.js and use it in your project.

The PR you linked is rather old and was [replaced by this one](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1470). Unfortunately all grouped bar implementations had design shortcomings and none are ready to merge, which is why we still have to use forks or branches of the code.

Instead of `renderType` the API on this fork changed to

```
.groupBars(true)
```

The fork and branch for the new PR are here:

https://github.com/jaklub/dc.js/tree/grouped-or-stacked-bars

The artifacts (dc.js and dc.css) can be found on the `grouped-or-stacked-bars-artifacts` branch.

One way to fetch them is using jsdelivr:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jaklub/dc.js@grouped-or-stacked-bars-artifacts/dc.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jaklub/dc.js@grouped-or-stacked-bars-artifacts/dc.css
```

Or, if you're using npm, you can declare the dependency as so:

```
"dc": "git+git@github.com:jaklub/dc.js#grouped-or-stacked-bars-artifacts"
```

Shorter version for any recent version of npm:

```
"dc": "jaklub/dc.js#grouped-or-stacked-bars-artifacts"
```

Although this is a fork of the last major version (3) of dc, it's compatible with the latest d3, as demonstrated in [this demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/tcraqj5e/6/).

[image: screenshot of grouped bars]

Clearly you need a lot more horizontal space in order to display grouped bars, but that's a separate issue.