# Does DC.js offer grouped barchart now

Tags: dc.js

I am working on some visualization project and I am in of need a grouped barchart but as i saw from old posts it was not available in dc.js. I am wondering if its now available in recent versions of DC.js

Comment: No change, [see previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520458/dc-js-grouped-bar-chart/67601565#67601565). We were unable to merge existing contributions because of code design / maintenance issues. Currently you have to use an old fork / branch. Best we could do is perhaps update the fork, but there is nothing we can merge yet.

Comment: Ok noted, thanks @Gordon